# Display Menu Title in Drupal please

Tags: php, sql, drupal, drupal-6, themes

I have a custom menu in Drupal.  Here is the code I use to display it inside my theme (page.tpl.php):

```
<h4>Site Information</h4>
<?php print theme("links", menu_navigation_links("menu-teaser-05")); ?>
```

Rather than display Site Information I would like to be able to pull out the Menu Title.  Short of doing custom SQL/code can anyone help.  The value I am looking for can be found at:

```
Administer -> Site Building -> Menus -> (Select Menu) -> Edit Menu -> Title
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the block the the menu module generates for each menu you create. It has the title of the menu, and all the menu items in the menu.

The block can be found in the block system: `admin/build/block`, where you can decide where it should be shown etc.

Comment: Do you mean the _links function in the theme?  I would only want this heading showing up for certain menus, not them all, hence my idea just to pull out the name in its own query.

Comment: I could use the block but I need to allow a (non-techy) to edit the menu title so having to go out and edit a block title is probably a step too far.

Comment: You cannot go more low-tech than using the block option.

Comment: I can get the block title to work but for this project, I need to allow the client to edit the Menu Title and have this pulled through.  Thanks for your help though.